# Should I use IN or OUT degree in Network Diffusion Model of Twitter network using iGraph?

Tags: python, graph-theory, social-network, igraph

I'm trying to run Independent Cascade Model for my Twitter graph to see who I have to stimulate to get the maximum cascade. This code is inspired by http://php.scripts.psu.edu/hxc249/code_segments/independent_cascade.py which uses Networkx. However, I modified a bit to be able to run with iGraph.

I create my network just OUT degree which corresponds to who I follow in Twitter. However, as far as I understand in order for a node to get infected, that node has to see the information. For example, only my followers would see that I tweeted something and if that node decided to retweeted my status that means the node is infected and the followers of that node can keep retweeting.

So, should I build my graph based on my followers instead of who I follow?

So, if I use `G.successors(mynode)` that would be all the nodes that potentially might be infected of the tweet I tweeted?

Here's my code

```
def independent_cascade_igraph(G, seeds, steps=0):
    # init activation probabilities
    for e in G.es():
        if 'act_prob' not in e.attributes():
            e['act_prob'] = 0.1
        elif e['act_prob'] > 1:
            raise Exception("edge activation probability:", e['act_prob'], "cannot be larger than 1")

    # perform diffusion
    A = copy.deepcopy(seeds)  # prevent side effect
    if steps <= 0:
        # perform diffusion until no more nodes can be activated
        return _diffuse_all(G, A)
    # perform diffusion for at most "steps" rounds
    return _diffuse_k_rounds(G, A, steps)

def _diffuse_k_rounds(G, A, steps):
    tried_edges = set()
    layer_i_nodes = [ ]
    layer_i_nodes.append([i for i in A])
    while steps > 0 and len(A) < G.vcount():
        len_old = len(A)
        (A, activated_nodes_of_this_round, cur_tried_edges) = _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges)
        layer_i_nodes.append(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
        tried_edges = tried_edges.union(cur_tried_edges)
        if len(A) == len_old:
            break
        steps -= 1
    return layer_i_nodes

def _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges):
    activated_nodes_of_this_round = set()
    cur_tried_edges = set()
    for s in A:
        for nb in G.successors(s):
            if nb in A or (s, nb) in tried_edges or (s, nb) in cur_tried_edges:
                continue
            if _prop_success(G, s, nb):
                activated_nodes_of_this_round.add(nb)
            cur_tried_edges.add((s, nb))
    activated_nodes_of_this_round = list(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
    A.extend(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
    return A, activated_nodes_of_this_round, cur_tried_edges

def _prop_success(G, src, dest):
    '''
    act_prob = 0.1
    for e in G.es():
        if (src, dest) == e.tuple:
            act_prob = e['act_prob']
            break
    '''
    return random.random() <= 0.1

independent_cascade_igraph(twitter_igraph, ['121817564'], steps=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is following B, then A has an OUT edge to B, that's right.

However, I agree it is not intuitive, since in the case of twitter the propagation of information goes from B to A. It is ok, provided you take into account that there is no propagation probability for out edges; i.e. you can influence your followers, but not the people you are following.

Thus, for the propagation you should use `G.in_edges` (that's in `networkx`, I haven't used `iGraph` but in the docs I see it should be `G.predecessors`). `G.sucessors` would give all the neighbors in `networkx`, nodes with both `in` and `out` edges; in `iGraph`, however, it gives only `out` edges. (Confusing!)

It is true that in the original code you provide it uses `G.sucessors`, i.e. all the neighbors in `networkx`. Do you have any context for that code, when it was used?

[This](http://www.sumankundu.info/articles/detail/How-To-Code-Independent-Cascade-Model-of-Information-Diffusion) is another piece of code, but this one if for twitter. Unfortunately it is in `java` but you can see it uses `G.in_edges`. But the algorithm is also described in English,

> ```
> Each node is evaluated as per the following steps, 
> 1. Push it to the stack
> 2. while stack is not empty
> 2.1 pop the node (v) from stack
> 2.2 consider it as active and put it into active sec
> 2.3 Repeat following for each **inbound neighbor** (u) of node
> 2.3.1 generate a random floating point number (rand) between 0 to 1.
> 2.3.2 if (propagation_probability(u, v)  <  rand)
> 2.3.2.1 if (u is not in active set) push u to stack
> ```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**:
After comments, I add my very simple code for the implementation using `networkx`. Of course, any feedback would be more than welcome. The algorithm itself is debugged, however I must say I am still trying to figure out better ways for the following:

- setting the probabilities for the propagation of each of the users
- validating the results
- how good the retweets are a proxy for the structure of the network (since downloading the followers is too slow due to Twitter's rate limits)

This is the method for the diffusion,

```
def single_diffusion(G, seeds, tot_users, debug=False):
    targets = list()
    actives = set()
    results = {}

    for seed in seeds:
        targets.append(seed)
        actives.add(seed)
        while True:
            target = targets.pop()
            if debug:
                print("t", target)
            for follower, u in G.in_edges(target):
                if debug:
                    print("f", len(actives), follower)
                    print(G[follower][target]['weight'])
                if random.random() < tot_users.loc[follower, 'p']:
                    if follower not in actives:
                        if debug:
                            print("a", len(actives), follower)
                        actives.add(follower)
                        targets.append(follower)
            if len(targets) == 0:
                if debug:
                    print("number of actives: ", len(actives))
                results[seed] = len(actives)
                break
            if len(actives) > len(tot_users):
                raise RuntimeError("infinite loop!")

    return results
```

where `tot_users` is a dataframe for all the users in the graph, and contains a column for the probability of distribution.

The loop for the results, and an example for calculating the mean.

```
results = {}
for i in range(num_iter):
    new_results = single_diffusion(G, seeds)
    if results != {}:
        for k,v in new_results.items():
            results[k] = results[k] + [v]
    else:
        for k,v in new_results.items():
            results[k] = [v]

for k,v in results.items():
    print(k)
    print(np.mean(results[k]))
```

Comment: I have do that in java as well. Can you provide the source code?

Comment: I meant that the link provides code in `java`. Well, it's kind of pseudo-code I guess. I'm working in python with `networkx`. However, I'm not using information from followers (rest api is too slow to get them for a big enough number of users), I'm using info from retweets to build the graph, but still not sure about the results, honestly!

Comment: Ok, the code too dirty to post it right now, but I will post it by the end of the week (i.e. the part that corresponds to the algorithm)

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.